# Trying to turn fluid width div into 100% wide modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, fluid

You can see an example of what I've got now [here](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/yFnle).

I'm trying to get the div that's 'full' to expand from the middle out, pushing the others out of the way in the process. What I've got now will push them to the left edge and then expand them. I know that this is because I've got `position:absolute`. Any ideas on how I can acheive this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of what I think you are describing: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKfAw

I removed display: table from div and set .min, .min p to width 0px with an overflow hidden and removed height 0%.

The issue why it was jumping is because you set all the min to 0 with the full floating left. That automatically pushed it to the left and then expanded out. Now all the divs are animating to 0 while .full is animating to 100%.

Comment: Yeah looks like the display:table was causing the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah displaying table will keep the width of all elements inside setting it back to block then allows you to animate the width to 0 with overflow hidden which hides the content.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "expand from the middle out". Here is a quick fix for your js:

```
$('div').on('click', function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.toggleClass('full');
   $this.siblings().toggleClass('min');
});
```

This only adds full class to the div which was clicked.

Comment: Right but because the parent section is more than 100% wide and I don't want to have the modal scroll, I need it to have the class of 'full' as well. Right now the div will move to the left edge of the screen and then expand from the right to fill the width of the screen. I would like for it to expand from both the left and the right at the same time to fill the entire screen.